# Can I get host hostname inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to have the hostname of the host in order to run entrypoint script, that runs accordingly (production, preproduction). How can I get the `hostname` and to set it as ARG inside Dockerfile. This docker file is used by docker-compose.yml.

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web
    container_name: 'nginx'
...
```

Dockerfile inside ./nginx folder:

```
FROM nginx:latest
ARG HOST_HOSTNAME=hostname
ENV HOST_HOSTNAME=$HOST_HOSTNAME
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
...
```

And inside docker-entrypoint.sh to be able to use ${HOST_HOSTNAME}. Also I want this code to be able to run on every machine without changing anything, but just adding new hostnames to docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass hostname though environment variable

Comment: I set the enviroment variable HOST_HOSTNAME, then I restarted and checked that is available. Then I deleted all images, did rebuild and the variable is not accessible in the docker-entrypoint.sh. Do I have to add this variable HOST_HOSTNAME on docker-compose level? (Also I changed inside the Docker file this row ARG HOST_HOSTNAME=$HOST_HOSTNAME)

Comment: Yes, you need to add it at the `docker-compose.yml` level.  Since the value is specific to the host you’re running it on, this is not something you would want to build into the image.